# Find docker image files on Windows

Tags: windows, image, docker, visual-studio-code, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak on docker and I have to change some files to build a custom theme in docker's image for Keycloak, but I can't find these files on my Windows system. How can I find and change docker images files on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Once an image has been built, you can't modify it.  In general, you can't directly modify the files in images or containers from outside of Docker.

You can build a custom Docker image starting `FROM` any image you want, and then `COPY` files into the theme directory:

```sh
FROM jboss/keycloak
COPY my-theme/ /opt/jboss/themes/my-theme/
ENV KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME=my-theme
```

```sh
docker-build -t my-keycloak .
docker run -p 8080:8080 my-keycloak
```

Or, you can bind-mount a host directory into the container.  This will allow you to directly edit the files in the host directory, and they will be reflected in the container (and *vice versa*), but it will not produce a reusable image that you could distribute.

```sh
docker run \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v $PWD/my-theme:/opt/jboss/keycloak/my-theme \
  -e KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME=my-theme \
  jboss/keycloak
```